# how to simply a list of about 99 domains to enable CORS on?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-headers

I currently have `.htaccess` file that lists dozens of domains to enable CORS to from my server.

I shortened my example below , but all the domain names are similar and the only part of the domain name that is changed is the 1 or 2 digit number after the www.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www48.example.com||www47.example.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
        Header merge Vary Origin
</IfModule>
```

so in this example i have CORS enabled for

```
https://www48.example.com
https://www47.example.com
```

I was wanting a simpler way to enable a list of of 99 domains with similar names. So all domain names are identical aside of digits 1 to 99 after the "www" , how can I achieve this without listing all 99 domain names individually?

```
https://www1.example.com
https://www2.example.com
....
https://www10.example.com
....
https://www40.example.com
....
https://www70.example.com
....
https://www99.example.com
```

Comment: Instead of using alternation for the full host names, match digits in the specific position? Something like `www[1-9][0-9]?\.domainname\.com`

Comment: can you expand your suggestion to include what i have ?

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work , anyone review and see if ok

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www[1-9][0-9]?\.example\.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
        Header merge Vary Origin
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That's fine, except for a few minor things regarding the regex: **#1** No need for the _capturing_ subgroups. **#2** The `s` on `https` should probably not be _optional_? **#3** If you re going to anchor the regex then why not anchor the start? **#4** `[0-9]` is the same as shorthand `\d`. So, it would become: `"^https://www[1-9]\d?\.example\.com$"`

Comment: And there's probably no need for the `<IfModule>` wrapper, unless these directives are considered _optional_?

Comment: Good solution but could've explained it a bit more

Comment: As @MrWhite mentioned, the capturing does appear to be necessary.  The subsequent _AccessControlAllowOrigin_ assignment uses $0, which would be the entire match.  So, ^https?://www[1-9]\d?\.example\.com$, would suffice.